# Extract a specific portion of connection string

Tags: python, regex, string, connection-string

Any way to extract what's after the `@`(if any) and before the next `.` (if any)?

Examples:

```
host
host.domain.com
user@host
first.last@host
first.last@host.domain.com
first@host.domain.com
```

I need to get `host` in a variable.

Suggestions in Python? Any method is welcomed.

Thanks,

EDIT: I fixed my question. Need to match `host` and `host.blah.blah` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> x = "first.last@host.domain.com"
>>> x.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]
'host'
>>> y = "first.last@host"
>>> y.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]
'host'
>>>
```

There will be an IndexError Exception thrown if there is no @ in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of `string.split` calls, the first using '@' as a separator, the second using '.'

Comment: +1 i think it's really the best way. Neither regex solutions given matche string without @.

Answer (score 0):

do a split by `'@'`, and then substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
'first.last@host.domain.com'.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
host = re.search(r"@(\w+)(\.|$)", s).group(1)
```

Comment: Nice one. I added a `|` after the `@` in case there is no `@`

Comment: @Amarghosh: You didn't fix it properly; `$` can match `\n` at the end of the string; use `\Z` instead of `$`.

Comment: @Alix: Why? Apart from the `\Z` thing, the pattern fails to match in other circumstances e.g. `foo@#` so just leave failure to match as being generally "invalid input".

Comment: @John That's a feature I need: to be able to specify a server name only e.g. `foo` or `foo.bar.tld` (it was not in my question though).

Comment: @John what if the string contains multiple lines and a line ends with host name as in `"user@host\nsome other text"`

Comment: Will not matche the first 2 examples from OP: ie without @ in the string.

Comment: @Alix, @Amarghosh: not finished with you yet :) ... using `\w` allows the underscore `_` (dodgy) but disallows the hyphen `-` (definitely not a good idea) ... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname ... I suggest use of `[-\w]` or `[-A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\w`

Comment: @Amarghosh: If the OP wants to allow trailing rubbish (including a newline), then just use `@([-\w]+)` with no end anchor.

Comment: @Amarghosh: I know that [-A-Za-z0-9] is the "correct" one, but out there in real world some folks have host names with underscores in them ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution:

```
re.search("^.*@([^.]*).*", str).group(1)
```

edit:
Much better solution thanks to the comment:

```
re.search("@([^.]*)[.]?", str).group(1)
```

Comment: (1) `re.search("^.*X")` is functionally equivalent to `re.search("X")` [except in the presence of newlines] and (as implemented) is horribly slower if X is not found. (2) The trailing `.*` (matches 0 or more of any character [except a newline]) is utterly pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Those are the great things to know.

Comment: Any trailing pattern that can match 0 characters is utterly pointless, whether it's `.*` or `[.]?` or something else -- you don't want what it matches, so don't put it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s="first.last@host.domain.com"
>>> s[s.index("@")+1:]
'host.domain.com'
>>> s[s.index("@")+1:].split(".")[0]
'host'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

hosts = """
user@host1
first.last@host2
first.last@host3.domain.com
first@host4.domain.com
"""

print re.findall(r"@(\w+)", hosts)
```

returns:

```
['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host4']
```